# Не работает тачпад на ноутбуке ASUS ZenBook UX433FA

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, драйвер

Не работает тачпад. Пару раз, после перезагрузки, он работал буквально минуту, после чего переставал работать. Перепробовал столько способов, ни один не помог.

`xinput`:

```
$ input
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:0400                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD IR UVC WebCam: USB2.0           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD IR UVC WebCam: USB2.0           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Строка с информацией о тачпаде из `/proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=0400 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN1200:00 04F3:0400"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN1200:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-ELAN1200:00/0018:04F3:0400.0001/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=903
B: MSC=10
```

Без пакета `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` `xinput` не видит тачпад.

P.S. Ubuntu 19.10. Видимо, начинает работать после долгого отключения.

P.P.S. И перестаёт после попытки (успешной) проскроллить тачпадом. Если скроллить нечего, то тачпад работает. Если что-то попытаться проскроллить - перестаёт. Когда он работает, в `/proc/bus/input/devices` он выглядит так:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=30b8 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN1201:00 04F3:30B8 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN1201:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-ELAN1201:00/0018:04F3:30B8.0001/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers list` чё показывает?

Comment: надо `evtest` на тачпад напустить и поводить пальцем, чтобы выяснить в иксах проблема или в нём

Comment: @donRumata `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

Comment: @PavelGridin Не выводит при любых действиях. С мышкой, например, работает

Comment: @Indentuu, может что-то ядро сообщает, попробуйте `dmesg|grep input`

Comment: @PavelGridin я обновил пост. В `evtest` это событие скролла, после которого тачпад перестаёт работать: https://pastebin.com/JrdYXVxC

Comment: @PavelGridin [результат](https://pastebin.com/Yb8PKtZP) `dmesg | grep input`

Comment: похоже ваш случай: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1778087

Comment: @PavelGridin видимо, решением является поменять ядро с 5.3.0 на 5.2.х

Comment: @PavelGridin, похоже, на RH больше телодвижений https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1543769

Comment: так правильно за rhel деньги платят

Comment: Проблема не зависит от ОС. На десятке и федоре ситуация аналогична: после «холодного» включения (если он был выключен минут 30 минимум) тачпад работает, пока не попытаюсь проскроллить. После этого он перестаёт отображаться даже в ОС как девайс и перезагрузки не помогают. На сайте асуса есть драйвера только под винду, да и только для версии с нумпадом на тачпаде. В общем, думаю, вопрос закрыт)